# How to count days between 2 rows multiple scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server, between, counting

I would like to count days from table like this:

[[image]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOk91.png)

I have 2 columns with status and date, I need to count how many days one row had status with 1 and 3, for example: first row has staus 1 second row has status 2 the difference between those two rows is 3 days, the same eight and nine row. All those calculation I neet to do in sql.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2017 express

Comment: It is so hard to cut and paste test data from a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for sql-server 2012. I was unable to find any documentation that would prevent this syntax in express.

```
DECLARE @t table(Status int, Date datetime)
INSERT @t
VALUES
(1,'2018-02-15'),
(2,'2018-02-18'),
(3,'2018-02-20'),
(2,'2018-02-23')

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT Date, lead(Date)over(order by date) NextDate, Status
  FROM @t
)
SELECT sum(DateDiff(day, Date, NextDate))
FROM CTE
WHERE Status in (1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you have analytic (aka window) functions  available ([Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), [SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234(v=sql.110).aspx), [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html)). The basic idea would be (using Oracle SQL dialect):

```
select
sum(trunc(next_date) - trunc(dat))
from (
select 
  status,
  dat,
  lead(dat) over (order by dat asc) next_date
from
      (  -- This is a "fake" data table
      select 1 as status, to_date('15/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 2 as status, to_date('18/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 3 as status, to_date('20/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 2 as status, to_date('23/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 4 as status, to_date('24/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 7 as status, to_date('27/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 9 as status, to_date('28/2/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 3 as status, to_date('1/3/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 14 as status, to_date('4/3/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 15 as status, to_date('7/3/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 1 as status, to_date('10/3/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      union all
      select 2 as status, to_date('14/3/2018' ,'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
      ) d
  ) d2
where
  status in (1, 3);
```

Other dialects may be slightly different but the idea is the same.

Comment: unfortunetelly lead is not recognized function name, and I am not db administrator to do this. I am using MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: @BogusławBoczkowski: SQL Server 2017 absolutely supports the `lead()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql